# UIImageView.center не вычисляет актуальные значения

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Всем привет! Сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой - на ViewController'е расположены несколько UIImageView, при вызове для любого из них  .center.x возвращается 120.0, а .center.y возвращает 64.0, где бы я их не размещал. С чем может быть связано и как получать актуальные сведения о расположении картинки на View?
UI и код:
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось исправлением метода на ViewDidAppear!

Вот что подсказали:

> потому что viewDidLoad сообщает о том, что все вьюшки загрузились, а загружаются они обычно с frame.origin = {0,0}. В вашем случае лучше смотреть в сторону viewDidLayotSubviews, который сообщает, что subview главной view, расположены правильно. НО, subview у subview ещё могут быть в начальной позиции.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы понять в чем ошибка попробуйте удалить все связи (IBOutlet) и заново их установить. И в методах viewWillApper: или viewDidApper: у объектов UIImageView вызвать свойство center и координаты вывести в консоль. Если проблема не решилась, попробуйте постепенно скрывать NSLayoutConstraint и проверять значение центра.

[image: На примере, видно для каждой UIImageView.center соответсвующие координаты центра относительно]

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/J5G9ORA.png
Связи переустановил, не помогло. Констрейнтов у картинок нет.
На скриншоте выделен как раз _ghost1

Comment: Для чего вы используете в Storyboard size classes? Попробуйте их отключить(Use Size Classes в Interface Builder Document в файле сториборда).  [На скриншоте пример, где отключается Use Size Classes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2yVpH7pUMDBOUwtQXg2YU1wX1k/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Решилось исправлением метода на ViewDidAppear, спасибо за подсказки!

Comment: Не за что) Главное вы нашли причину проблемы, что бы в дальнейшем не натыкаться на подобный баг)

Comment: @ВладимирАлёхин Если проблема решена, ответьте сами на свой вопрос.